# jQuery Select All Elements That Have a Title

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, tooltip, title

I need to apply a tooltip plugin to a bunch of different elements on my page. The only common property to work with a jQuery selector is that they all have a `title` property set.

I tried `$('[title=*]')` as a selector but this didnt work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simply:

```
$('[title]')
```

See also - [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

Answer (score 19):

Also `$('[title][title!=]')` should work but catches only elements that have title set and not empty (not `title=""`)

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. You need to do `$('[title][title!=]')`

Comment: @GilBirman you are right, I'm going to change my answer accordingly

Comment: FYI this works on jQuery 2.1.0 but causes a Sizzle error on jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: Added an answer that works on both versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23701424/137067

Answer (score 9):

Try `$('*[title]')`, more about attribute selectors [here on the W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers that only selected elements with non-empty title attributes failed for me in jQuery 2.1.1. This works on all versions that I checked:

```
$('[title][title!=""]')
```